# Do I need to change motherboard in changing video cards?

Tags: graphics-card

I just found a 2GB video card GDDR5, my current video card is 1 GB ddr2. Do I need to change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out is if your motherboard has an expansion slot that supports the new card. The new card is most likely a [PCIe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) card, so you need one PCIe slot on your motherboard. In my ears DDR2 sounds like it could be an older AGP bus card, so you really need to check what your motherboard supports.

Also you have to make sure that your power supply can handle the load from the new card, and that it has all the connectors that the new card need. The connectors could in most cases be fixed with adapters though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My current motherboard is ECS GeForce 6100pm-m2 btw.

Comment: According to the [spec.](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=857&MenuID=20) it as x16 PCIe slot which is good.

Comment: Soo, I could install GDDR5 ? (Excitement)

Comment: GDDR5 is a memory type used on the latest graphics cards. What I'm saying is that you could install a PCIe graphics card, the memory type on it doesn't matter regarding if you could install it or not.

Comment: http://reviews.cnet.com/video-components/galaxy-geforce-gt610-graphics/4505-3025_7-35487730.html just found this awesome card, is it compatible with ECS GeForce 6100pm-m2 v2.0 ?